# convert X-Y data.frame to matrix for every column in R efficiently

Tags: r, matrix

I have found away to do this using reshape2 but it is quite slow and doesn't quite give me exactly what I want. I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(expand.grid(1:10,1:10))
colnames(df) <- c("x","y")

for(i in 3:10){
df[i] <- runif(100,10,100)
}
```

I run:

```
require(reshape2)

matrices<-lapply(colnames(df)[-c(1:2)],function(x){
  mat<-acast(df, y~x, value.var=x, fill= 0,fun.aggregate = mean)
  return(mat)
})
```

there I have a list of matrices for each value vector in my data, I can transform this into an array of 1:10,1:10,1:10 dimension, but I am looking to see if there is a faster way to do this as my datasets can contain many value columns and this process can take a long time and I can't seem to find a more efficient way of doing it..

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look at `dcast` in the `data.table` package.  It is typically much more efficient than `reshape2`.

Comment: Describe what you want to do instead of simply referring to "this" as if your title explains itself

Comment: I think my answer is one of the more efficient methods of solving the problem as I understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data.frame is stored regularly as you say, you could accomplish this in a `for` loop, which may actually be faster than casting:

```
# preallocate array
myArray <- array(0, dim=c(10,10,10))

# loop through:
for(i in 1:10) {
  myArray[,,i] <- as.matrix(df[df$y==i,])
}
```